# Laravel 5 with Blade... using jQuery I can't set data-attribute when using helper function route(), but works with relative paths

Tags: jquery, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

Laravel 5.6.28 with Blade Templates... 
Laravel is new to me - open to suggestions. Thanks!

Using jQuery, I'm trying to add a class 'active' to the link in the navbar accociated with the page loaded and it works great if I use relative paths, but when using a Laravel Blade route() helper function like in the My Account link, the "data-path" attribute never gets set.

I'm not sure if using the attr() method is the problem or maybe the each()? Any assistance is appreciated. Maybe I should be using vue.js? Thanks!

```
<div id="navwrapper" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="/" class="active" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="{{ route('loginregister') }}">My Account</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var basePath = window.location.href;
    var pathName = window.location.pathname;

    // remove active class on all nav links
    $("#navwrapper ul li a").removeClass("active");

    // get current link and add active class to it
    $("#navwrapper ul li a").each(function() {
        var dataPath = $(this).attr("href");
        var dataPathNoBase = dataPath.replace(basePath, '');
        $(this).attr("data-path", dataPathNoBase);
        if (dataPathNoBase == pathName) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force Laravel to use relative paths by passing false as the 3rd parameter like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="{{ route('loginregister',[], false) }}">My Account</a>
</li>
```

Alternatively, If you don't have to use jQuery to solve this, you can do something like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="{{ route('loginregister') }}" 
         @if(request()->is('loginregister')) class="active" @endif >
         My Account</a>
</li>
```

Personally, I like using custom blade directives so I would put this in my AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(){
    Blade::directive('isActiveLink', function ($route, $name) {
        return request()->is($route) ? 'class="active" ' : '';
    });
}
```

and then in the blade template I just use:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="{{ route('loginregister') }}" @isActiveLink('loginregister')>My Account</a>
</li>
```

Of course, you can build the entire link in the directive if you want.

Here's a link to the relavant Laravel Doc on [Extending Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#extending-blade)

Comment: Thanks Axeame, those are some great options! I like the custom blade directives the best and will work on that asap.  My friend Pedro helped me debug my present code and we found a solution as well for those interested. The problem was that the basePath was grabbing the entire href, my mistake. So I changed it to... var basePath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;    and it's working now. Thanks again Azeame, I really like your solutions.